# Qt5 обработка сигналов потока

Tags: многопоточность, qt5

Класс

```
class Logger: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void write(QString txt); //записываем в файл
    void process();
public:
    Logger();
private:
    void createFile();
    QFile LogFile;
};
```

Создаю поток этого класса:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Logger* log = new Logger();
log->moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), log , SLOT(process()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(write(QString)), log , SLOT(write(QString)));
thread->start();
```

Помогите с созданием потока, который будет принимать большое количество сигналов, помещать их в очередь и обрабатывать. 
Если очередь пуста, то поток должен заснуть на, скажем, 1 секунду. 
И как вызывать `SIGNAL WRITE` из любого класса программы?

**UPD:** С очередью разобрался. При многочисленном вызове сигнала `write` они будут в очереди `EventLoop`, т.к. слот находится в другом потоке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При чём тут потоки? В контексте C++ потоки это stream-классы.
Посылать лог-сообщение по сигналу - довольно неэффективно. Сигналы/слоты раз в 20 медленнее чем вызов функции. Для логов это не допустимо. Кроме того, классы которые создают лог-сообщения должны быть QObjects.

Скройте пишущий thread внутри класса Logger. Сделайте в Логгере Queue защищённую мьютексом, в которую бутете согранять тексты логов передаваемых в функции write(). Сохраняйте логи в файл в отдельном threаd-е.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно тебе лучше использовать `event`, вместо сигнала. 
Тогда тебе не придется коннектить сигналы из всех классов в классе-обработчике, а просто в этом классе сделать обработку события `write`.